# Automate RStudio processed RMarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, pandoc, r-markdown

I have an RMarkdown file that I use to generate a nice HTML report.
The problem is, I want to be able to automate it so that it can run on a headless server. As such there will be nobody there to start Rstudio and press the 'knithtml' button and it seems that Rstudio is doing a LOT of additional magic like having it's own version of pandoc, running all the necessary commands, applying css styles etc.

How can I take this report and generate the same thing Rstudio is generating when I press the 'knithtml' button, but by just running an R script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using

```
rmarkdown::render("/PATH/TO/YOUR.Rmd", output_file="/PATH/TO/YOUR/OUTPUT.html")
```

instead. This assumes you've got the `rmarkdown` library loaded on your headless box. It will use the system pandoc, but make sure it's 1.12 or higher.

Here's what `knit2html` does (via the "R Markdown" tab near "Console"):

[image]

Here's a side-by-side. Left is clicking the button, right is running the command:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After a lot of brute force, I got the same result as RStudio with this command line:

```
"path\to\Rscript.exe" -e "rmarkdown::find_pandoc(dir='path/to/RStudio/bin/pandoc'); rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd')"
```