# What is a neat command line equivalent to RStudio's Knit HTML?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

What is a neat command line equivalent to RStudio's Knit HTML? Given an `.Rmd` file, you can use RStudio to knit `.html`, `.docx` and `.pdf` files using Knitr. It would be great to shift this process completely to the command line. My approach so far:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('test.Rmd')"  # This creates test.md
pandoc test.md >> test.html
```

This works fine, but the resulting `test.html` does not come with the same pretty make over as in RStudio. Any suggestions how one should best knit `.Rmd` files to `.html` via the command line, and end up with a pretty `.html`?

Extra question: What would be the best command line solution for `.pdf` or `.docx`?

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286797/automate-rstudio-processed-rmarkdown/26287127#26287127) to see what RStudio does under the covers to make their "pretty" HTML output.

Comment: `Rscript -e 'library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render("[path]/test.Rmd", "html_document")'`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", "html_document")
```

Comment: Great, this works! The complete command line command is: `Rscript -e 'library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render("/path/to/test.Rmd", "html_document")'`

Comment: Shorter shell command, based on @elke's great comment above, using the default output format and removing the library call (redundant with  `::`) `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd')"`

Comment: When clicking the RStudio icon the page opens (or the PDF in my case). Is it possible to specify in the command line to open the PDF after knitting?

Answer (score 13):

My simpler command-line script, similar to Tyler R.'s:

In your `.profile` or similar, add:

```
function knit() {
    R -e "rmarkdown::render('$1')"
}
```

Then, on command line, type `knit file.Rmd`

EDIT: For nice autocomplete, see comments

*I set up output format in the Rmd header: `output: github_document` or similar*

Comment: This is simple and efficient. It is also useful to restrict tab-completion to `.Rmd` files to save some typing.

Comment: yes, looking to future readers to add this auto-complete functionality!

Comment: @baxx I use bash, so I added stuff to my `.bashrc` instead of `.profile`. I added `complete -f -X '!*.Rmd' knit`. See as an example: https://github.com/Freguglia/dotfiles/blob/d0be8c1b4f68af0605bac438c31ec98792e4aa0f/.bashrc#L97

Answer (score 12):

Following up on the accepted answer, I've drafted a bash script called "knitter" that will do everything needed, all the user needs to do is input: `./knitter file.Rmd file.html` or `./knitter file.Rmd file.pdf`.

The script is below:

```
#!/bin/sh

### Test usage; if incorrect, output correct usage and exit
if [ "$#" -gt 2  -o  "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "********************************************************************"
    echo "*                        Knitter version 1.0                       *"
    echo "********************************************************************"
    echo -e "The 'knitter' script converts Rmd files into HTML or PDFs. \n"
    echo -e "usage: knitter file.Rmd file.{pdf,html} \n"
    echo -e "Spaces in the filename or directory name may cause failure. \n"
    exit
fi
# Stem and extension of file
extension1=`echo $1 | cut -f2 -d.`
extension2=`echo $2 | cut -f2 -d.`

### Test if file exist
if [[ ! -r $1 ]]; then
    echo -e "\n File does not exist, or option mispecified \n"
    exit
fi

### Test file extension
if [[ $extension1 != Rmd ]]; then
    echo -e "\n Invalid input file, must be a Rmd-file \n"
    exit
fi

# Create temporary script
# Use user-defined 'TMPDIR' if possible; else, use /tmp
if [[ -n $TMPDIR ]]; then
    pathy=$TMPDIR
else
    pathy=/tmp
fi
# Tempfile for the script
tempscript=`mktemp $pathy/tempscript.XXXXXX` || exit 1

if [[ $extension2 == "pdf" ]]; then
    echo "library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render('"${1}"', 'pdf_document')" >> $tempscript
    Rscript $tempscript
fi
if [[ $extension2 == "html" ]]; then
    echo "library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render('"${1}"', 'html_document')" >> $tempscript
    Rscript $tempscript
fi
```

Comment: Great idea to have a script for that. Unfortunately your script has some bugs (e.g. the second argument is required, but is basically ignored - only the file extension is considered; the script requires `bash`, but is started with `!/bin/sh` etc.), so I created a [corrected version](https://gist.github.com/ximeg/9d1a2d543c8959725b1c9bace196efd5). Now the second argument specifies the output format.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me on my toes!

Comment: If you use the version of @RKiselev, the syntax would be `./knitter <input_file_with_extension> <output_file_extension_only>` for example `./knitter input.Rmd pdf`

Answer (score 0):

```
getwd()
setwd("C:Location of the RMD File")

# To make it in to PDF you can use the below code also
rmarkdown::render("Filname.Rmd")

# To make it in to PDF you can use the below code also
rmarkdown::render("Filename", "pdf_document")
```

I Typed the above in to a R Script and triggered it from Python command prompt and solved my requirement:)
Kindly note : if it doesn't work.. Try to install latex and try again.. All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

From the mac/linux terminal, you could run:

```sh
R -e "rmarkdown::render('README.Rmd')"
```

(replacing `README.Rmd` with whatever file you wish to knit)