# Is there any way to open multiple R markdown files and knit them at the same time?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have several RMD files in one folder and I need to knit them one by one everyday to get html for each of them. Is there any way or function that I can open them at the same time and knit them by running only few lines code or one function?

Comment: you can write a script using commands like these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32183333/what-is-a-neat-command-line-equivalent-to-rstudios-knit-html/55860195. Exactly how you do that depends on what OS you are running and where exactly the files are coming from and where you want to write to. It would be better if you could provide more detail and ideally some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

did you have a look at this chapter: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html. I think that is exactly what you will need.

Comment: Could you include some relevant code which addresses the issue into your answer? Link only answers are generally discouraged. Thank you.